# ArrayList: Isso é certo ou tem forma melhor para fazer?

Tags: c#, arraylist, cast

Sei um pouco de java, mas agora estou me aventurando no C#, mas veio uma duvida aqui:
No java instanciamos um ArrayList assim:

```
ArrayList<Tipo> nomeArray = new ArrayList<>();
```

Recuperamos um valor assim:

```
nomeArray.get(1).getNome();
```

E pelo meus teste aqui com C#, parece instancia assim:

```
ArrayList nomeArray = new ArrayList();//Não declara o tipo, estranho
```

E parece que se recupera assim:

```
((Tipo) nomeArray[1]).Nome;//Toda vez que tenho que recuperar tenho que usar um TypeCast?
```

Essa é a forma correta? Ou tem forma melhor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No c# você deve utilizar  o tipo `List<tipo>` que funciona basicamente como o ArrayList em Java.

No c# o ArrayList está marcado como obsoleto.

ArrayList estava disponível antes que os genéricos fossem implementados  no .NET 2.0.

Não há vantagem em ArrayList.Visto que os genéricos são amplamente utilizado por desenvolvedores. 
Recomendo usar `List<>` ou outro tipo de coleções ou listas genéricas.

Exemplo:

```
List<Tipo> variavel = new List<Tipo>();
variavel.add(variavelDoTipo);

var recuperaValor = variavel[0];
```

List utiliza o método `add()` para adicionar um elemento à coleção (O tipo deve ser compatível com o tipo da lista).

Para recuperar o valor, você utiliza a sintaxe de acesso ao um array comum.

Exemplo:

```
var variavel = nomeLista[0];
```